# How can I upgrade Silverlight so that I can stream Netflix /

Tags: macos, install, netflix, silverlight

How can I install/upgrade Silverlight so that I can run Netflix?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this Microsoft link: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight, and follow the instructions there.

It will auto-download a silverlight.dmg installation file, which you double-click to launch.